# Tearing on onboard intel graphics with mythbuntu hd playback

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, mythbuntu

Im having tearing occur at the top 5% of the screen with an intel onboard graphics when playing HD video during motion. I'm using mythbuntu 12.04 with updated kernel and updated intel graphics driver packages.
I've tried using Options "TripleBuffer" "True" in xorg conf with no success.
I've also turned on the compiz workarounds suggested here https://bugs.launchpad.net/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/755841 with no success

This is the xvinfo output:

```
X-Video Extension version 2.2
screen #0
  Adaptor #0: "Intel(R) Textured Video"
    number of ports: 16
    port base: 88
    operations supported: PutImage 
    supported visuals:
      depth 24, visualID 0x21
    no port attributes defined
    maximum XvImage size: 2048 x 2048
    Number of image formats: 5
      id: 0x32595559 (YUY2)
        guid: 59555932-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71
        bits per pixel: 16
        number of planes: 1
        type: YUV (packed)
      id: 0x32315659 (YV12)
        guid: 59563132-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71
        bits per pixel: 12
        number of planes: 3
        type: YUV (planar)
      id: 0x30323449 (I420)
        guid: 49343230-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71
        bits per pixel: 12
        number of planes: 3
        type: YUV (planar)
      id: 0x59565955 (UYVY)
        guid: 55595659-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71
        bits per pixel: 16
        number of planes: 1
        type: YUV (packed)
      id: 0x434d5658 (XVMC)
        guid: 58564d43-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71
        bits per pixel: 12
        number of planes: 3
        type: YUV (planar)
```

Kernel is Linux mythtv 3.4.0-030400-generic #201205210521 SMP Mon May 21 09:22:02 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

intel driver version is xserver-xorg-video-int 2:2.19.0-0ubuntu1~xup1 X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver

Cpu is Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2120 CPU @ 3.30GHz with 8gb ram.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the following work around?

Bug 37686 - [SandyBridge] Video tearing
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37686#c47

This bug report contains a number of tips to try that might work for you.